# Pagination with Alamofire and realm.io

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, realm, alamofire

I have an api which could look like `http://URL/news/:lastloaded/:size` where `lastloaded`and `size` is the range of objects the api should return. This api returns a list of different news, which i want to show in a tableView. However in order to make it effective i wan't to make some kind of pagination, so that not all objects is loaded into the tableView. This i've achieved through simple variables like

```
let pageSize = 20
var lastLoadedPage = 0
```

however how do i make sure that the database in my case realm.io always is up to date with all the news from the api. I can easily change the api and add more parameters if it makes this easier? What is best practice? i'm using [Alamofire](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire) and [realm.io](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Realm itself doesn't actually require pagination. The data is saved straight to disk, and then only the properties that are required are lazily paged in as they are called. As such, it's very memory-efficient, so much to the point where managing blocks of objects in memory (like pagination works) isn't necessary.

If you want to 'simulate' pagination with Realm, it's simply a matter of querying for all of the objects as a List, and then pulling out a sub-set of the objects you wish to display.

That all being said, it's probably still wise to paginate your calls to the web API so you don't needlessly download more news items than you require, but once they're downloaded and saved to Realm, you won't need to worry about any similar device-side logic. :)